# K-Means on MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, machine-learning, k-means, nosql

I want to query a collection on MongoDB with K-Means.

Description of my collection: Each document is a list of fields, som of strings, some of reals, some of integers, some of categorical/boolean.

Description of my query: a document from the same model of documents specified above.

The algorithm: 
Upon query, to run k-means on a collection and find the k-clusters.
After, to find the most close cluster to query, let say by cosine similarity or other known metric.
Finally to return all the documents that are from the specific cluster.

If it cannot be done by MongoDB i will be happy if you have any alternative. 
Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB is a database designed for information storage and retrieval and not for running complicated machine learning algorithms - you can store your data in MongoDB for processing in k-means and store the results in MongoDB but MongoDB isn't going to help you perform the k-means clustering. Alternative tools better suited for k-means computation are storage in Hadoop and k-means processing with Mahout on top of that. Note, however, that k-means heuristics aren't realtime algorithms. Except for very small amounts of data, you will need to compute the clusters ahead of time and queries should simply return cluster membership. You can use MongoDB to store the computed cluster information and serve queries about cluster membership after running k-means in Mahout or with some other ML library.

Comment: what IR services mongoDB has ? any ranking method to retrive results?